# allowed explicit any type global variable used as non-any type function's returned value

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

this code compiles in typescript:

```js
let varTest: any;

const funcTest: () => number = () => {
    return varTest;
};
```

why is that? What's the logics behind this?

Comment: `any` is assignable to all types. Try `const numTest: number = varTest;` to see that it also doesn't error. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any

Comment: @VLAZ alright, it actually disables the check until the number return type. the caller of funcTest will think it always has a number returned, but it could be wrong. Right?

Comment: Yes. `any` is an escape clause from the type system. And as such *should be used very sparingly*. In my experience most bugs when using TS come from using `any` and losing type safety as consequence. If you want a safer type that could represent "anything", go with `unknown`.

Comment: `unknown` errors as you expect. `any` allows any usage. https://tsplay.dev/w8JaEm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because TypeScript compiler ignores type checking for `any`. That means `any` is a valid type for all the types in typescript. For example,

```
let a: number = 0;
let b: any = "this is string";

a = b;
```

The above code compiles WITHOUT an error because TypeScript sees that the type of `b` is any so it can be assigned to a variable with any (string, number, boolean, etc...) type of value.